# Android get certificate chain

Tags: android, certificate, keychain, chain

I'm building a app that signs some data and is supposed to send the 3-tuple `data, signature, certificate-chain` to a server. The server then checks the signature against the certificate and checks whether the provided certificate is signed by a fixed CA. I already installed the certificate on my android device and now I want to use it in my app.
My problem is: how can I retrieve the certificate chain (no private key) to send it to the server for verification? I looked at the `keychain` stuff but I don't see a way.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are You sure that you have to send cert chain file?

Comment: To clarify: I'm aware of the `getCertificateChain()` method which returns `X509Certificate[]` but I'm lost on how to continue from there. I was expecting a function like `getEncoded()` or similar.

I thought that the server needs the certificate and the chain to verify that the data has been signed by a good certificate.